# Windows XP File Sharing Technical Details

Tags: windows-xp, smb

Can anyone point me to a good technical article on how files and printer sharing works in Windows XP.

Googling hasn't been very successful.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It uses the [SMB protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).